# Why doesn't this regex match?

Tags: regex, c++11

```
std::cout << std::regex_match(std::string("f 1/1/1 3/3/1 4/4/1"), std::regex("f \d+\/\d+\/\d+ \d+\/\d+\/\d+ \d+\/\d+\/\d+")); // -> 0
```

I expect the above regular-expression to match the given string, but it does not. What's wrong with it?

It does match on https://www.regex101.com/, and when tested in Notepad++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues with your code, both related to invalid [*escape-sequences*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape):

1. `"\d"` is interpreted as an escape-sequence, the resulting string (passed to `std::regex`) will not contain what you expect — instead use `"\\d"` to properly get a slash followed by the letter `d`.
2. `"\/"` is not a valid escape-sequence, and there really is no need for you to escape `/`, instead leave it as if (`"/"`).

---

#### Working Example

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

```
int main () {
  bool result = std::regex_match (
    std::string ("f 1/1/1 3/3/1 4/4/1"),
    std::regex  ("f \\d+/\\d+/\\d+ \\d+/\\d+/\\d+ \\d+/\\d+/\\d+")
  );

  std::cout << result << std::endl; // 1
}
```

Comment: That's it thanks ;) Didn't know you need to double-escape.